# Swift: How can I get the song titles on an album

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am new to Swift!  I’m trying to write a basic music player.

This is how I successfully got the list of Albums from 1 Artist.
The Artists name was passed in to this 2nd View Controller by having its title set in the 1st View Controller.

```
let qryAlbums = MPMediaQuery.albumsQuery()

let predicateByArtist = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: self.title, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumArtist)
qryAlbums.filterPredicates = NSSet(object: predicateByArtist) as? Set<MPMediaPredicate>

let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "albumIdCell")
let rowItem = qryAlbums.collections![indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel!.text = rowItem.items[0].albumTitle
```

BUT, the following, similar code, does NOT work.
The Album Title name was passed in to this 3rd View Controller by having its title set in the 2nd View Controller.

```
let qrySongs = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()

let predicateByAlbumTitle = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: self.title, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle)
qrySongs.filterPredicates = NSSet(object: predicateByAlbumTitle) as? Set<MPMediaPredicate>

let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "songIdCell")
let rowItem = qrySongs.collections![indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel!.text = rowItem.items[0].title
```

Thank you ahead of time!!!

Comment: What specifically is going wrong with the song query? Are there no songs being returned?

Comment: In the Albums VC, I get the list of all Albums by the selected Artist (neatly put in the cells of the Table View).  In the Songs VC, I get 1 Album title, actually its the title of the selected Album, and nothing else.

Comment: Found it.  Had to change the line in the songsQuery to:
        
    let predicateByAlbumTitle = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: self.title, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle)

Comment: HOWEVER.  I think the songsQuery isn't good enough.  What if the music library contains 2 albums with the same name?  Can anyone help with with a double filter?

Comment: You have the property id of the album from your previous search. If you base the song predicate on that, only that album's songs should be returned.

Comment: Thanks Carter.  As far as I know, I don't have albums with the same name, so its difficult to test.  I was thinking ahead.  I basically did a compound predicate by doing 2 addFilterPredicate (1 for the Artist and 1 for the Album Title).

Comment: On my songs view controller, I can't figure out how to change the focus to the next cell in the table when the next song starts to play!  I know that I can use: player.nowPlayingItem, but I don't know where or how to set the focus.  I've been searching most of the day.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by focus of cell, but when the song changes (I'm guessing there's a callback for that) you can tell your UITableView to reload the corresponding rows. As the rows match up by index to the cells, you can choose to update only those two cells.

Comment: The table is made of rows of song titles (that are on the previously selected album in the last VC).  When you get to this VC, you click a song.  That song is "highlighted" with a light grey color and the album begins playing starting with that song.  The player is set up to play the rest of the album.  When the player starts playing the next song, right now, the previous song is STILL "highlighted".  That's what I have to change.  I just learned that I should be setting up an "observer", to receive "notifications".  Still, if it's up to me to "highlight" the next sell, I'm not sure how.

Comment: When your observer reports that a song has changed, use `[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[PREVIOUS_SONG_INDEX_PATH,CURRENT_SONG_INDEX_PATH] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];` to reload those two rows. When you load rows in general, check to see if that specific row is the current song, and "highlight" it accordingly- then whenever you reload a row it will automatically "highlight" if it is the current playing song and "unhighlight" if it's not playing any more.

Comment: Thanks again, but I have no idea how to work with indexPath.  All I know is that in: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {}, I know the cell (song) the user clicked because it's value is indexPath.row (which prints as an integer).  In: func nowPlayingItemChanged(notification: NSNotification) {}, I could "count" to figure out which cells need to be reloaded, but i don't know how to put that knowledge into indexPath.  Plus the nowPlayingItemChanged() is triggered twice when I click a song.

Comment: Ok, I figured out indexPath. And thanks to Carter, I've got the "highlighting" working!  Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Using MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle (as stated in the comments), solved it.  Thanks!